# jQuery: Show / Hide Multiple Elements Based on Partial Class Name

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, filter

I've been trying to figure this out, and think I need filter or find?  But, I've gone through lots of iterations and still haven't been able to nail it down...

**What I'm trying to accomplish:**

1. Option selected from the filteritem dropdown
2. Get value of item and show span.item-ii with inner html matching the
   value
3. Get class starting with lid- of span.item-ii
4. Show p.ptext items with the same class and hide the rest

**My markup looks similar to this:**

```
<select name="filteritem" id="filteritem">
  <option value="">- Select One-</option>
  <option value="Feliformia"> Feliformia </option>
  <option value="Caniformia">Caniformia</option>
</select>

<span class="item-ii lid-34 bigtitle">Feliformia</span>
<span class="item-ii lid-2 bigtitle">Caniformia</span>

...

<p class="ptext lid-34 moderate-me">Stenoplesictidae</p>
<p class="ptext lid-34 moderate-me">Percrocutidae</p>
<p class="ptext lid-2 moderate-me">Amphicyonidae</p>
<p class="ptext lid-2 moderate-me">Canidae</p>
```

Not sure it's worth including, but so far, I have this... (although, tips on how to make it better would be great...)

```
  $('select#filteritem').live('change', function() {
        var itemselection = $(this).val();

        if(itemselection == '') {
          $('span.itemii').show();
        } else {
          $('span.itemii').each(function() {
                $(this).hide();
                var itemtext = $(this).html();
                if(itemtext == itemselection) {
                   $(this).show();
                }
          });
        }
  });
}
```

Comment: Guessing that's just an oversight but you have a typo in the code. In your HTML markup you use class "item-ii" but in javascript you target "itemii"...

Answer (score 0):

I would almost change the select to be something like this

```
<option value="34"> Feliformia </option>
```

and the code would be simple

```
 $('select#filteritem').live('change', function() {
  var itemselection = $(this).val();
  $('.ptext').hide();
  $('span.itemii').hide();
  if(itemselection == '')
     $('span.itemii').show();
  else
     $('.lid-' + itemselection).show();
 });
```

Comment: you could also make the value be Feliformia-34 and then pull 34 from it but if you dont need the value to be text, then dont make it text

Answer (score 0):

To make it work, you need to do lot of work-around and you need to understand how the logic is  working.

Finally, this is how you need to do.

Refer my **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/t8rkf/1/)**

### HTML:

```
<select name="filteritem" id="filteritem">
  <option value="">-Select One-</option>
  <option value="Feliformia">Feliformia</option>
  <option value="Caniformia">Caniformia</option>
</select>
<br/>
<span class="item-ii lid-34 bigtitle">Feliformia</span>
<span class="item-ii lid-2 bigtitle">Caniformia</span>

...
<br/>
<p class="ptext lid-34 moderate-me">Stenoplesictidae</p>
<p class="ptext lid-34 moderate-me">Percrocutidae</p>
<p class="ptext lid-2 moderate-me">Amphicyonidae</p>
<p class="ptext lid-2 moderate-me">Canidae</p>​
```

### JQuery:

```
$('select#filteritem').change(function() {
    var itemselection = $(this).val();
    if (itemselection == "") {
        $('span.item-ii').show();
        $('p.ptext').show();
    } else {
        $('span.item-ii').each(function() {
            if (itemselection == $(this).text()) {
                $('span.item-ii').hide();
                $(this).show();
                var classList =$(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);
                $.each(classList, function(index, item) {
                    if ($('p.ptext').hasClass(item)) {
                        $('p.ptext').hide();
                        $('p.ptext.'+item).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});​
```

### CSS:

```
.item-ii {
    display:block;
}​
```